# Replace specific part with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace the textarea value with something else, using C# regex. Right now I have this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<textarea.*>(.*)</textarea>");
string s = "<textarea>test</textarea>";
string a = regex.Replace(s, "abc");
```

Except this prints `abc` instead of `<textarea>abc</textarea>`. I want to make it as dynamic as possible,

So something like this

`<textarea rows="20" class="style">test</textarea>`

Should become

`<textarea rows="20" class="style">abc</textarea>`

Thanks!

Comment: Your stars are greedy. Try making them lazy by adding question marks: `"<textarea.*?>(.*?)</textarea>"` and see if you have any better luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use capture groups and then put them in the output.  Like this:

```
void Main()
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("(<textarea.*>)(.*)(</textarea>)");
  string s = "<textarea>test</textarea>";
  string a = regex.Replace(s, "$1abc$3");
  Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```