# Replace part of XML by using regex capture group

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture a part of an XML string and replace a captured value with a new one.

I have the following code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<ns1:AcctId>(?<AcctId>.*?)</ns1:AcctId>");
Match match = regex.Match(Xml);

string AcctId = match.Groups["AcctId"].Value;

string IBANizedAcctId = IBANHelper.ConvertBBANToIBAN(AcctId);

newXml = Regex.Replace(oldXml, regex, IBANizedAcctId); //DOES NOT WORK!
```

So I want to capture the AcctId in the `ns1:AcctId` XML element. Then I want to replace this one with a new value by converting the BBAN to IBAN and replace the value. The first part works, but I do not know how to accomplish the last part (I did find an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409072/replace-specific-part-with-regex), but I do not understand it).

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: ok... for some reason it won't let me post my answer... :(

Comment: here are the 2 changes i made to your existing code: Match match = regex.Match(oldXml); -and- string newXml = oldXml.Replace(AcctId, IBANizedAcctId);

Comment: Cannot answer it either: but I found this solution thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex#6005637) answer: I know that the last part should be: `Xml = Regex.Replace(Xml, regexString, string.Format("$1{0}$3", IBANizedAcctId));` where the regexString has three capturing groups: `string regexDestAcctIntString = "(<ns1:AcctId>)(?<AcctId>.*?)(</ns1:AcctId>)";` The `$1` and `$3` refer to respectively the first and third capturing group and replace the middle with the new value. 80% sure it works.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv that is even more logical. :)

Comment: try it out... mine will work 100% as well, and across your entire Xml string. Not just the match. Up to you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<ns1:AcctId>(?<AcctId>.*?)</ns1:AcctId>");
Match match = regex.Match(oldXml);

string AcctId = match.Groups["AcctId"].Value;

string IBANizedAcctId = IBANHelper.ConvertBBANToIBAN(AcctId);

newXml = oldXml.Replace(AcctId, IBANizedAcctId); //should work...
```

Comment: I want to capture all occurences of `<ns1:AcctId> *** </ns1:AcctId>`, and they can contain different numbers.

Comment: I accepted the answer since it does work! But my requirement now is a bit different. I made a new question for that one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489039/replace-al-matches-of-regex-with-manipulation-on-specific-capturing-group).