# Replace all matches of regex with manipulation on specific capturing group

Tags: c#, regex

I have different Xml strings that can contain one or more parts in the following format:

```
<ns1:AcctId>47862656</ns1:AcctId>
```

The value in the middle can change. I want to replace all occurences of this `<ns:1:AcctId>` element with a manipulated value (from BBAN to IBAN to be specific).

I have made the following method in the `XMLModel` class with a property `Xml` (a XML-string):

```
string regexString = "(<ns1:AcctId>)(?<AcctId>.*?)(</ns1:AcctId>)";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexString);
Match match = regex.Match(Xml);
string AcctId = match.Groups["AcctId"].Value;
string IBANizedAcctId = IBANHelper.ConvertBBANToIBAN(AcctId);

Xml = Regex.Replace(Xml, regexString, string.Format("$1{0}$3", IBANizedAcctId));
```

The idea here is that the `regexString` has three capturing groups, and I replace the middle value (the account number) with the account number converted to IBAN.

Unfortunately, this code does not work: 1) it does capture the value of `AcctId`, but it does not replace it correctly since it loses the last `</ns1:AcctId>` part. 2) it replaces all occurences of the match with the value captured in the first one, while it should replace every occurence with the specific one captured.

Is there any way to do this in C#? And if so, can someone give me some pointers on how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the usual don't use regex to manipulate XML.

```
string regex = "(?<=<ns1:AcctId>).*?(?=</ns1:AcctId>)";
Xml = Regex.Replace(Xml, regex, delegate(Match m) {
                           return IBANHelper.ConvertBBANToIBAN(m.Value);
                         });
```

This uses positive look ahead and look behind so that the match is just the account number and then the overload to Regex.Replace the takes a match evaluator.

Comment: Nice! :) I use the method of Thomas since it is more appropriate, but I guess this is the answer to the question. :-)

Comment: It would be cleaner to match the account id with `\d+`, rather than resorting to complex regex features such as lookbehind assertions...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I wasn't sure whether BBAN was purely numeric, if so just use `\d*` instead of `.*?`. But you'd still want the lookbehinds so that you are only adjusting the AcctId tags

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use regex to manipulate XML, they're not the appropriate tool for that and won't always work. For instance, the XML file could use a namespace prefix other than `ns1`, mapped to the same namespace, and it would be semantically equivalent, but your regex wouldn't work anymore.

You should use an XML parser instead; the easiest to use is Linq to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(Xml);
var ns1 = XNamespace.Get("http://TheNamespaceMappedToTheNs1Prefix");
var elements = doc.Descendants(ns1 + "AcctId");
foreach (var e in elements)
{
    e.Value = IBANHelper.ConvertBBANToIBAN(e.Value); 
}
Xml = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for your answer. In this particular case I thought a regex was best, but your method is more appropriate and works like a charm. It takes all seperate `AcctID` values and replaces it with the new value specific to the specific element. Thanks a lot!