# Only capture element with Linq to XML if parent is of specified type

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I received a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489039/replace-all-matches-of-regex-with-manipulation-on-specific-capturing-group/23489197?noredirect=1#23489197) which explained how to select an element from XML in a certain namespace:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(XmlString);
var ns1 = XNamespace.Get("http://TheNamespaceMappedToTheNs1Prefix");
var elements = doc.Descendants(ns1 + "MyElement");
```

I was wondering if it is possible to only select elements that have a certain parent element name. So only get `MyElement` if the parent element is `MyParentElement`. Is this possible? And if so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 doc.Descendants(ns1 + "MyElement")
    .Where(x=>x.Parent.Name.LocalName=="MyParentElement")
```